# Binding an user control to WPF ComboBox?

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, combobox

I want to bind an user control as an item of a ComboBox, is this possible?

I want to get a ComboBox like this:

[image: ComboBox]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

do you want all items in your combobox to render like your picture? so if you have 4 items it should look like this?

[image]

if yes, the easiest way would to create a datatemplate for your type of object you wanna show in your combobox.

if not you should specify your question